# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 2019 with macOS Big Sur

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, grub-efi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on MacBook Pro:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)
- macOS Big Sur 11.5.1
- 2,6 GHz 6x Intel Core i7

I created new partition on Mac SSD for second OS and bootable USB with Ubuntu 21.04 installer (installations from USB with versions 20.04 and 20.10 failed). While OS installation I was getting executing grub-install error. I've tried to repair grub and make Ubuntu bootable on MAC after Ubuntu installation but performing all scripts and recommendations I found is failed.

I also tried to install Ubuntu from live Ubuntu session on bootable USB drive with 'ubiquity -b' ('b' option set to not install grub while installation) but in the end all suggestions to make Ubuntu bootable on MAC lead nowhere.

So, best case scenario after all attempts I have Ubuntu installed on Mac SSD partition with no working boot loader.

Is there anyone who could install Ubuntu on Mac with similar configuration or who knows how to do it? Please, share recommendations and tips.

Comment: You [can try to get Ubuntu installed on a 2019 MacBook Pro](https://gist.github.com/gbrow004/096f845c8fe8d03ef9009fbb87b781a4), but a lot of things will simply not work. Apple does not make it easy to install Linux on their newer hardware.

Comment: Thanks for that! But it seems Ubuntu 20.04 is uninstallable  on macOS 11.5.1. While trying to install 20.04 system says you need to install a boot drive update for this to work. After updating (clicking on 'Update') nothing changes, system again and again says you need to install the boot drive update

Comment: As I have already stated, Apple makes it *very* difficult to install Linux on their hardware. If you must run Ubuntu on macOS, you will find it works much better via VirtualBox than bare metal. This is suboptimal for some tasks that may work better with direct hardware support, such as games or blockchain toolsets, but is generally the most reliable method with the more recent Intel-based hardware.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install a solid Ubuntu with working grub, mouse, touchpad and wi-fi on MacBook with said configuration I have used a distribution from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/marcosfad/mbp-ubuntu), where Ubuntu versions for T2 MacBook are posted. I've installed release v20.04-5.7.19-1 (download an ISO image, write it on USB stick with balenaEtcher, create a new disk partition for second OS, enable booting from external media, then run Ubuntu Live and use Ubiquity to install).
To enable wi-fi I followed steps [proposed AdityaGarg8](https://github.com/marcosfad/mbp-ubuntu/issues/46):

- install necessary [kernel modules with DKMS](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/dkms/)
- upgrade kernel from [v5.13.12-1](https://github.com/AdityaGarg8/T2-Big-Sur-Ubuntu-Kernel/releases/tag/v5.13.12-1)
- follow [this guide](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/wifi/)

After that I have Ubuntu running without problem on Mac with configuration that described in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- Hold cmd-R while booting and type your user password when prompted.
- Open the "Startup Security Utility" from the Utilities menu.
- Set Secure Boot to "No security" and Allowed Boot Media to "Allow booting from external or removable media".
- Restart holding option and select USB drive.