Booting a Mac with Ubuntu data stick/dvd?
I am trying to boot a 2019 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu from a prepared data stick, This looks like a well-worn path. The Mac OS controls (Sonoma) lock me out at every turn.  One mistake had me reloading Sonoma from the web.
A published suggestion to boot from a dvd has me puzzled- the bootable file is 5GB and I can't get that on a dvd. Alternatively, a less defensive box may be the solution. I'm new to this so I may be missing the obvious to skilled practitioners; any  help is appreciated.

Use a bootable USB instead of DVD. Also, for more details of setting up drivers, see https://t2linux.org/

Also, instead of regular Ubuntu images, install these https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu/releases/tag/v6.7.8-1

You don't advise what's "locking you out at every turn", but I think you may be looking for this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1358869/380067

Apple started omitting internal optical drives in their Macs starting in 2012. The last Macs with internal optical drives could read (and therefore boot from) Dual Layer (DL) DVDs, which had a capacity of 8.5 GB. For Macs without an internal drive, Apple does offer an external SuperDrive. However, I believe being able to boot from a SuperDrive is not guarenteed.

I think you are referring to the "Finding help" section for Create a bootable USB stick on macOS.

If your Mac still refuses to boot off your USB stick you may find it
easier to boot and install off an Ubuntu DVD instead. See our How to
burn a DVD on macOS for further details.

Your Goal
I think you are trying to install Ubuntu onto an Apple Mac computer.
Try This First

Download the ISO file
Copy the ISO file to a USB storage drive (thumb/flash drive) with something like Etcher
Boot to the USB drive from the computer and install


If you want to use your USB stick with an Apple Mac, you will need to
restart or power-on the Mac with the USB stick inserted while the
Option/alt (⌥) key is pressed.

Confusion Part 1
The guide is titled for creating an Ubuntu installer FROM Mac, but it includes installing To Mac.
Confusion Part 2
There is a mixture of old terminology with modern process regarding bootable .iso files.  We used to install Linux, Mac, or Windows from a round DVD disk that contained an ISO file.  Now, we still use the file format but it goes on a USB stick that you plug into the computer.  In 2024, when you're installing Ubuntu on a computer it's probably easiest to do it as I described above.
Confusion Part 3
DVD is mentioned in the guide for those that might be familiar with the older way of doing things.  There's nothing wrong with doing it that way.  I personally consider PXE using something like netboot XYZ to be superior to USB.  When you're just getting started though, taking the approach that's most comfortable may be best.  Then you can improve your process later on.
Best of luck to you and I hope you enjoy Ubuntu!
